# Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient is ignored as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android

Tags: java, android, http, file-upload, androidhttpclient

I added http mime library in gradle dependencies as:

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.4.1'
```

But after compiling Android Studio is showing following warnings:

```
Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient is ignored as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
```

How to get rid of these warnings?

**EDIT:**
If it is in-built provided by Android, then when I write code for file uploading like this:

```
 MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
```

then It does not recognize `MultipartEntity` as a class and shows error. Then why it is conflicting?